# How to validate a login in my database (MVC C#)

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a page with login and I am doing with the MVC C # method ... I wanted to know how I validate if the username and password I am typing has in the database ... The way you are entering anything typed.

```html
**HTML**

@model QuestionarioSaude.Model.UsuarioModel

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
                    {
                        <div style="border:1px solid red;">
                            @ViewBag.Message
                        </div>
                    }
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Usuario, new { @placeholder="Digite o seu usuário", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Usuario)
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Senha, new { @placeholder="Digite a sua senha", @class="form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Senha)
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Entrar" />
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Model**

```
public class UsuarioModel
    {
        public int? IdUser { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o usuário", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite a senha", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public string Perfil { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(string Usuario, string Senha)
        {
            UsuarioModel usuariomodel = new UsuarioModel();
            usuariomodel.Usuario = Usuario;
            usuariomodel.Senha = Senha;

            if (ModelState.IsValid) //checa se é valido
            {
                if (usuariomodel.Usuario != "" && usuariomodel.Senha != "")
                {
                    UsuarioBLL usuBll = new UsuarioBLL();
                    usuBll.VerificarUsuario(usuariomodel);

                    Session["UsuarioID"] = usuariomodel.IdUser.ToString();
                    Session["NomeUsuario"] = usuariomodel.Usuario.ToString();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

**DAL**

```
public bool UsuarioUnico(UsuarioModel usu)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            bool result = false;

            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO like @Usuario and SENHA like @Senha";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdUser", usu.IdUser);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usu.Usuario);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", usu.Senha);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Perfil", usu.Perfil);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nenhuma linha encontrada");
            }
            reader.Close();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code?

Comment: In what way does the code you already have not work as expected?  What actual problem have you encountered?

Comment: You are not validating with the database. If I type anything in the (html) fields it enters the system. But I just want to get in if you have the user in the database. Understood ?

Comment: You really need to salt and hash your passwords (Sehna). It should NOT be stored in plain text.

Comment: @MarcosHenrique: Where do you *try* to validate with the database?  When *you* debug *your* code, where specifically does it fail?  Understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one helped me and I got other help and I got what I wanted ... Thank you for not helping me and still reducing the reputation of the question.

Below is what I have changed...

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(UsuarioModel usuariomodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //checa se é valido
            {
                if (usuariomodel.Usuario != "" && usuariomodel.Senha != "") //se não estiver vazio
                {
                    UsuarioBLL usuBll = new UsuarioBLL();
                    var result = usuBll.VerificarUsuario(usuariomodel);

                    if (result)
                    {
                        Session["UsuarioID"] = usuariomodel.IdUser.ToString();
                        Session["NomeUsuario"] = usuariomodel.Usuario.ToString();

                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário ou senha incorretos.");

            return View();
        }
```

**DAL**

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
            reader.Close();

            return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize result in 'usuariounico' in false

```
bool result = false;
```

And never change it, so always is false.

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                result = true;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
```

If there is any row, it mean there is a user with that user and pass, so the result is ok

Comment: Can you resolve it? If yes i'd appreciate you select it as the accepted answer

Comment: Dude, it did not solve completely because it was not just what was wrong ... I managed to clean it myself. But thanks for the help.